# Can I switch between onClickListener and onLongClickListener on the run time?

Tags: android, events, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I added OnClickListener and OnLongClickListener for the item in the ViewHolder class of the RecyclerView's adapter

The idea is basically, when I want to select an item I should long click on it for the first time then I should do a normal short click to select the other items

The following is the code for the view holder with the interfaces for the long click and the normal click
The interfaces will be implemented by the fragment's class and the method of the interfaces will be overriden. As the code shows, I make if-condition that changes between the long click and the normal click linstener according to MultipleSelectionOn (Which is a boolean variable). However, when I click a long click on the item, the MultipleSelectionOn variable changes to true but the onClickListner is not executed.

```
public class DevicesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener{

    LinearLayout device_item_layout;
    TextView title,status;
    ImageView deleteIcon, selectionBtn;

    OnItemClick onItemClick;
    OnItemLongClick onItemLongClick;

    public DevicesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClick onItemClick, OnItemLongClick onItemLongClick) {
        super(itemView);

        device_item_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.device_item);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        deleteIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteIcon);
        selectionBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectionBtn);

        this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
        this.onItemLongClick = onItemLongClick;

        if(MultipleSelectionOn == false) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }else{
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        Log.i("MultipleSelectionOn ", String.valueOf(MultipleSelectionOn));

        onItemLongClick.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);

        MultipleSelectionOn = true;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.i("MultipleSelectionOn ", String.valueOf(MultipleSelectionOn));

        onItemClick.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);

    }
}



public interface OnItemLongClick{

    void onItemLongClick(int position, View view);

}

public interface OnItemClick{

    void onItemClick(int position, View view);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first initialise both `setOnLongClickListener` and `setOnClickListener`. And for the action there are multiple ways you can do that -

1. Create a view that overlaps the recyclerView's item when user long press it. It'll mimic the selection of an Item. And also take a flag like `isSelected`. The value of flag will be changed when user long press an item. Add a condition in `setOnClickListener` that if `isSelected` is not equal to `true` then execute whatever inside the click listener. The flag `isSelected` will be in the adaptor.
2. You can take that `isSelected` in put it in the modal class of which the recyclerView implemented. And in `setOnLongClickListener` update its value to `true` or `false` accordingly. And then add a condition in `setOnClickListener` that if `isSelected` is not equal to `true` then execute whatever inside the click listener. But this time you use the value of `isSelected` associated with object of modal class at that specific position.

Comment: Thank you, your answer solved it ! 
but I didn't understant the second point, what is the modal class ?

Comment: What I meant is, suppose you have a `List<User>` which you've passed to adaptor. So every item of the list i.e; `User` has a flag like `isSelected`. And by default it'll be `false` for every item in list.

Answer (score 0):

When init your `ViewHolder`, you should set both `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListener`

```
public DevicesViewHolder(...) {
    ...

    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I removed the if-conditions here
 if(MultipleSelectionOn == false) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }else{
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

but it now I can select item using normal click and long click, and this is not the idea that I want
the idea is that I should first click long click on an item and then I can just click normal click on any other item to get it selected

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
public interface OnItemLongClick {

    void onItemLongClick(int position, View view);

}


public interface OnItemClick {

    void onItemClick(int position, View view);

}

public class DevicesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout device_item_layout;
    TextView title, status;
    ImageView deleteIcon, selectionBtn;

    OnItemClick onItemClick;
    OnItemLongClick onItemLongClick;

    public DevicesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClick onItemClick, OnItemLongClick onItemLongClick) {
        super(itemView);

        device_item_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.device_item);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        deleteIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteIcon);
        selectionBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectionBtn);

        this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
        this.onItemLongClick = onItemLongClick;
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        Log.i("MultipleSelectionOn ", String.valueOf(MultipleSelectionOn));

        onItemLongClick.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);

        MultipleSelectionOn = true;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.i("MultipleSelectionOn ", String.valueOf(MultipleSelectionOn));
        if (MultipleSelectionOn) {
            onItemClick.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I need to put condition to ensure the setOnClickListener is not executed in the first time when I click a normal click on item,
the idea is that I should first click long click on an item and then I can just click normal click on any other item to get it selected